# javascript using a button to fill a canvas object

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So basically the javascript draws two triangles, one with a blue border and the second with a green border. I have a button that when is pushed it should fill the triangle with a blue border blue.

Currently it does not work but when the {} are removed from the if statement at the bottom it colors the green bordered triangle green, im not sure why this happens.

Any tips would be very helpful!

```js
window.onload = draw;

function draw() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
    ctx.moveTo(600, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(500, 200);
    ctx.lineTo(700, 200);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
    ctx.moveTo(500, 210);
    ctx.lineTo(700, 210);
    ctx.lineTo(600, 410);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();

  }
}

function fillColor() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  if (ctx.strokeStyle == "blue") {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fill();
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="700" height="410"></canvas>
```

Comment: ctx.strokeStyle will give you #code of the color. Please try to console.log(ctx.strokeStyle). it may give u a hint

Comment: so is strokeStyle the wrong thing to be comparing to?

Comment: Your question is not clear, what you want to achieve

Comment: So basically I want to find the triangle with the blue outline and fill it in blue.

Comment: Please se my answer  with the sample code

Comment: To fill the blue triangle in `fillColor` you must redefine it's path: `ctx.beginPath(); ctx.moveTo(600, 0); ... ctx.closePath`. Then you can `ctx.fill()` it with blue.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare rectangles with the stroke color.You need to change your fillColor function a little bit . Please see the below code it may help you

HTML

```
<body>
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="700" height="410"></canvas>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
window.onload = draw;

function draw() {
 var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
 if (canvas.getContext) {
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.beginPath();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
  ctx.moveTo(600, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(500, 200);
  ctx.lineTo(700, 200);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  fillColor(ctx,'blue');
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
  ctx.moveTo(500, 210);
  ctx.lineTo(700, 210);
  ctx.lineTo(600, 410);
  ctx.closePath();
  fillColor(ctx,'red');
 }
}

function fillColor(ctx,color) {
   ctx.fillStyle = color;
   ctx.fill();
}
```

You need to call the fillColor() function after creating each rectangle with the color to fill.

Comment: Is it not possible to have the triangles drawn first then hit a button that finds the triangle with a specific colour and fill it in?

Comment: It is possible if you implement a floodfill algorithm, but you should simply just redraw it using a different color at the same place

Comment: Any advice in how to do that?